# Why does cannot be 0 command = Sell_price!=0; evaluate to error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

- solve this row
  Sell_price
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAE4f.jpg)

Comment: Looks like homework. And don't post in images

Answer (score 1):

You need to `create table` with all the mentioned columns.

`sell_price` column must be `not null` and do not allow 0 in it.

So it must be:

```
Create table product_master
( 
...
...
Sell_price number(8,2) not null check(Sell_price <> 0), -- not null and check will be required in your case
..
);
```

Cheers!!